# How can I make celery die after there are no more tasks to be run?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, django-celery

I have a celery task that is memory-intensive and I want it to run in an expensive AWS server that stays off most of the time.

A celery beat will schedule the task once a day, but it can also be scheduled manually through a web application (== django).

Scheduling the task is a matter of sending a message to a rabbit queue.

Then I would like to issue a command using AWS api to turn on my expensive server, and have it start the workers, 
wait for them to die after there are no more tasks, and shutdown (and save some money because the server is off).

I know how to script AWS to turn on my server. The problem is: how do I tell celery to run tasks until the queue is empty **and then die**?

Is there a command parameter I can give it, or do I need to come up with some kind of hack for that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this through Celery? Why not start the expensive process directly and let it simply exit when done?

Comment: The task may take a while to run. While it is running a request to run another similar task might come in. It needs to be queued.

Comment: Just to be clear: the intention here is to turn off the server after it's not needed anymore (to save money in AWS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @iurisilvio and @douglas-camata for your answers. I think I found an ideal solution using some ideas from you guys :-)

I created a simple monitor myself with this django command (my app is django after all) == `wait_celery_idle.py`

```
import time
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from core.celery_utils import celery_count_status as ccount
import celery


class Command(NoArgsCommand):

    help = "Waits until celery is idle"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        while _count() > 0:
            time.sleep(5)


def _count():
    cinspect = celery.current_app.control.inspect()
    return ccount(cinspect.active()) + ccount(cinspect.scheduled()) + ccount(cinspect.reserved())

def ccount(d):
    k = d.keys()[0]
    return len(d[k])
```

I then start the celery process normally like: `./manage.py celery worker -c 1 --pidfile /tmp/celery.pid`

Then I start a second process (`wait_and_die.sh`) to monitor celery and die if it is idle for too long.

```
#!/bin/bash
# wait_and_die.sh

./manage.py wait_celery_idle
kill $(cat /tmp/celery.pid)
sleep 10
sudo shutdown -h now
```

PS: this works only if I'm using rabbit as a queue infrasctructure - the `cinspect.*` methods return None if I'm using the django db as a queue (using `CELERY_BROKER_URL='django://'` in settings.py)

Comment: Once the worker has stopped, what starts it again? I've not used celery beat but looking at the doc I'm not seeing that it starts workers. Did I miss that somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Celery worker is just a dumb horse. Something else must monitor the worker and trigger an event if the worker is waiting for tasks.

Use [Flower](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flower) to monitor your Celery cluster and [their API](http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#api-reference) to consume the worker activity.

Flower has a beautiful dashboard with workers/tasks data, the information is there and they have an API.

Comment: I didn't know flower. Good one!

Answer (score 2):

My advice: create a callback to run after your task finishes. This callback will fire a request to your web application with the AWS instance information and use this information to shut it down.

EDIT: this assumes you route each task into a new machine. For example, while waiting to be destroyed that Celery worker should not accept any new task.

EDIT2: also a good idea might be letting this expensive task itself send the request to the web app to destroy the Amazon instance and also kill the Celery worker (check http://www.pythondoc.com/celery-3.1.11/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker)/